# Conditionally display Element using Aurelia

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

So I have my `auth` class injected into my `main.js`:

```
import {Auth} from 'auth';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Auth)
export class App {
    constructor(auth) {
        this.auth = auth;
    }

    get isLoggedIn() { return this.auth.isLoggedIn; }
}
```

so in my `app.html`

```
<form>
    <!-- form login elements -->
</form>
```

how do I make this element conditionally display based on my app getter function.

Comment: What about the if/show binding? `<form if.bind="isLoggedIn"></form>` http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.1.1/doc/article/cheat-sheet/6

Comment: i couldn't find that, will have a look, cheers

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use if.bind to conditionally bind your DOM elements.

```
 <form>
      <div if.bind="auth.isLoggedIn">
        <!--this DOM element will be bind only if auth.isLoggedIn is true-->
      </div>
 </form>
```

Optionally, you can also use show.bind but that will only hide your DOM elements. Where as if.bind will not render it on your page.

Comment: where is the `if` binding in the docs? can't find it anywhere! argh

Comment: Its hidden in the cheat sheet: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/5

Comment: the check only seems to be applying at construction. If the conditional value changes, the binding seems not to notice.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to remove element completely from markup when condition is not met, you can use `if.bind` (as @Pratik Gajjar answered):

```
<template>
  <div if.bind="auth.isLoggedIn">
    <!--this DOM element will be bind only if auth.isLoggedIn is true-->
  </div>
</template>
```

If you need to conditionally set `display: none` on element, you can use `show.bind`:

```
<template>
  <div show.bind="auth.isLoggedIn">
    <!--this DOM element will be shown only if auth.isLoggedIn is true-->
  </div>
</template>
```

For details have a look at http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/6.

Answer (score 1):

So I created a value converter:

```
export class CssdisplayValueConverter {
    toView(value) {
        return value ? 'none' : 'display';
    }
}
```

Then in my app.html:

```
<require from='css-display'></require>

<form css="display: ${isLoggedIn() | cssdisplay}"></form>
```

Boom, done.

Comment: Worth pointing out to anyone else who encounters this question and this answer specifically: you can just use `show.bind` instead of the above value converter. It effectively does the same thing and comes out-of-the-box in Aurelia.

`<form show.bind="!isLoggedIn"></form>`

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use a value converter when Aurelia has this functionality built in.

Comment: Well, when you use from beta :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if.bind` and `show.bind` for binding an element by checking a condition